# What does solr support ? A Relational Data base or a NoSql DB's

Tags: solr, solrcloud

I would like to know weather SOLR supports a NoSql Database or a Relational Database?

Thanks

Comment: Solr's data model is not relational.

Comment: Are you asking about SOLR's data structure? Or are you asking if Solr can import from RDBMS/NoSQL?

Comment: @SrikanthVenugopalan Yes. I am asking about SOLR's DataStructure.

Comment: @MauricioScheffer SOLR's Data model is like NoSQL just like Columnar Databases like HBase, Cassandra ? But SOLR has schema.xml which is similar to Rational DB? I am confused with this.

Comment: A defined schema does not imply a relational model.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solr internally uses Apache Lucene for indexing. Details about the index file structure is available in the docs [here](http://lucene.apache.org/core/4_9_0/core/org/apache/lucene/codecs/lucene49/package-summary.html#package_description).

Technically this can be classified as a NoSQL store.

Comment: Thanks for the docs, appreciated. Is there any difference between Solr Segments and Lucene Segments. I think Solr internally uses Lucene's indexing and merging the segments.

Comment: Sorry @Venkat - That is too much of an implementation detail for me, haven't bothered getting into that detail. You should try asking this on one of the Solr Mailing lists.